# Motorola MC9596 kiosk mode

Tags: symbols, windows-mobile-6.5, motorola, kiosk-mode

I'm developing my first application to **MC9596 mobile device** (OS: Windows Mobile 6.5). The goal is to create an application in '**kiosk mode**', that means user can only use this application on mobile device and nothing more. It is not allowed to run other application nor change windows settings.
I was able to hide windows button and upper status bar (if somebody will be interested, I will post it) and of course it is not a problem to run application maximized on top.
What giving me nights without sleep is **hardware button** on the scanner. Below the display there  is a greeen and red button on the sides. Whatever I do, after pressing the green one phone is displayed together with windows button. And after pressing windows button you just got access everywhere.

I tried following solutions found while googling:
Changing registry under 
**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Symbol\ProgrammableKeys**
or
**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Shell\Keys**

and tried to use **UnregisterFunc1 in coredll.dll.**

Unfortunately neither helped.

I have no problem with changing registry settings or using external dll-s, just need to find a solution. I am already overdue with this task and just spent 3 days trying to find a solution for this problem.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, my collegue accidentally helped me with this problems, so finally the solution is:

```
[DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)] static extern bool
AllKeys(bool bAllKeys);
```

Than just call:

```
AllKeys(true);
```

According to blogs.windows.com:

> This function allows your programs to request that all key presses be
>   sent directly to the requesting application. Normally some buttons are
>   intercepted by the operating system for its own use, but games and
>   input - intensive applications may want access to these buttons for
>   their own use.

Comment: BUT using this will not bring you the F1 and F2 (soft menu keys) to your compact framework application: http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2012/09/20/windows-mobile-cf-how-to-catch-f1-and-f2-in-weh/ - Besides covering the whole screen and suppress the 'OS' function keys, there are a lot more possible pitfalls for a kiosk mode application. Possibly you should think about using a kiosk mode SDK (SPB software for example) or the vendors (Motorola) kiosk mode launcher or a generic launcher like Odyssey AppLauncher. ~josef

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I am not gonna use F1-F2 keys anyway and did not found any other problem yet with this solution. Anyway, thank you for you help!